# Native Express AdView Not Displayed

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have added the native express adview from firebase into my app
it loads fine when i use the test id provided by them but when i replaced it with my publisher id and unit id,it stops displaying it

LogCat

```
Starting ad request.
Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3C5C50F4B6108021A73AB0588B9E62C0") to get test ads on this device.
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
Failed to load ad: 0
Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

Code
XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
                android:id="@+id/adView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx80"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

JAVA

```
     MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), APIClass.PUBLISHER_ID);
NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Will the ads get displayed when i add publish the app to play store

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> With Native Ads Express, your NativeExpressAdView size needs to fit in the range of sizes you picked in the AdMob Front-end. In this case, Smart banner is not big enough.
>
> See the [Choosing a Size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express#choose_a_size) section in the docs for what the ranges are for the Native Ads Express templates. Now see how the sizing of [Native Ads Express](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express) works, since you chose SMART_BANNER as your size (FULL_WIDTHx80).
>
> Let's say you're running this app on a Nexus 5 in portrait. The smart banner will be sized at `360x50`. When you compare that against the requirements for the Native Ads Express templates, you'll see that even the Small template requires a height of 80dp. Because your size doesn't fit the requirements, you won't ever see an ad.
>
> **Try changing the size to ads:adSize="300x250"**. That size fits all 3 templates, and so you should get an ad back. I just tested it myself and it worked for your ad unit. For more precise measurements, double check which size you picked on the AdMob front-end, and make sure the width and height of your ad fits within the ranges.
>
> We'll investigate more internally why the error code indicates internal error. This could be surfaced a bit better. However, I'm going to close this issue though for the reasons mentioned above.

Answered from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/27)

Comment: I solved my problem by changing adSize from 320x150 to 300x250.Thanks mate.

Comment: Also solved my problem by changing 350x200 to 300x250.

Comment: The question has been asked on NativeAds. Why the answer talks about Smart banner ?

Answer (score 0):

try one of this sizes:

XML:

```
ads:adSize="320x50;  // BANNER
ads:adSize="468x60;  // FULL_BANNER
ads:adSize="320x100; // LARGE_BANNER
ads:adSize="728x90;  // LEADERBOARD
ads:adSize="300x250; // MEDIUM_RECTANGLE
ads:adSize="160x600; // WIDE_SKYSCRAPER
```

Java:

```
AdSize.BANNER
AdSize.FULL_BANNER
AdSize.LARGE_BANNER
AdSize.LEADERBOARD
AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE
AdSize.WIDE_SKYSCRAPER
```

example:

setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
***or***
setAdSize(new AdSize(320,50))